# Running a kivy app, at one screen, for any keyboard button pressed, am i able to key into TextInput widget?

Tags: python, kivy

I want the user to be able to key into the textinput widget, without the person moving the mouse and click on the textinput widget. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `focus:True` and it should take focus to the `textinput` field

Comment: Hi as im not using kv language but just python itself. I tried TextInput(text="Enter Something", focus=True ,multiline=False) , it seems like it did focus onto the TextInput Widget. However, im not able to key in any input to the TextInput.

Comment: could you make a screenshot or a screencapture video for this. I am not sure what could be the cause of you not being able to enter the text - so I would like to take a look at it for more clarity